# You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled

Tags: mysql, laravel, ubuntu, laravel-5, laravel-migrations

I am running a laravel migration from jenkins that creates a stored procedure and the following error appears:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1419 You do not have the SUPER privilege an  
  d binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_  
  trust_function_creators variable) (SQL:                                      
              CREATE TRIGGER ...
```

How can I fix this and allow the migration to create triggers, etc. without problems.

Comment: It's all in the manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-logging.html

Comment: If I login as root from console I cant create triggers right from mysql console. However, from phpmyadmin (not login as root) I can't create triggers, and get the same error as with laravel migration.

Comment: Also, I don't think adding log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1 is the solution.

Comment: [This](https://catonrug.blogspot.com/2022/07/zabbix-62-you-do-not-have-super.html) solved it for me (It occured after a zabbix upgrade but might just be the same). *Note:* your `/etc/my.cnf.d/` might be `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/`.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this:

mysql -u USERNAME -p
set global log_bin_trust_function_creators=1;

Answer (score 0):

I changed the database connection user to "root" for the time of the migration. After it was successful, I switched it back to the normal user.